# (Javascript) How do I get a random number in between two user inputted variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, random

I am working on an assignment and I am having difficulty writing up the function to get a random number between two variables.

Basically what I want is the script to prompt you for the first number followed by the second then give me a random number in between those two.

How do I get a random whole number in between two user inputted variables?
What I am doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```js
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
var videogames = prompt("How many hours of video games have you played last month?");

function getRndInteger(age, videogames) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (videogames - age)) + age;
}
document.write(getRndInteger(age, videogames));
```

This question is different than the other question because mine is a random number between two variables. The other answer wouldn't work for me.
Thanks again!

Comment: Is the code failing? Are you getting an error? What is the expected result vs what you are getting?

Comment: certainperformance answered my question thank you, it wasn't adding up correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out which variable is smaller first, so that the number added at the end is the lower, and so that the difference `(high - low)` is positive. You also need to make sure that you're working with *numbers* - `prompt` returns a string, so `+ <string>` will result in concatenation, not addition.

```js
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
var videogames = prompt("How many hours of video games have you played last month?");

function getRndInteger(...args) {
  const [low, high] = [Math.min(...args), Math.max(...args)];
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low)) + low;
}
document.write(getRndInteger(age, videogames));
```

Note that this generates a range `[low - high)` - the "low" point is included, the "high" is not. (eg, from a range of 2-4, 2 is a possible result, as is 3, but 4 is not.) If you want to include `high`, add one to the difference:

```js
var age = prompt("How old are you?");
var videogames = prompt("How many hours of video games have you played last month?");

function getRndInteger(...args) {
  const [low, high] = [Math.min(...args), Math.max(...args)];
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
}
document.write(getRndInteger(age, videogames));
```

Comment: The problem with that is what if they are someone could be 25 and game 30 hours in a month or be 30 and game 25 hours in a month, is there a way to take a random number between the two variables? one variable will be higher than the other based on user input.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the answer does - it determines the lower and the higher, then multiplies the difference by `Math.random()` and adds the lower bound.

Comment: You rock man im gonna try it out, thank you!!!

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mind helping me with one more question? I posted it in a separate post, i feel like im close but i cant figure it out